# Dask `.dt` after conversion

Tags: dask

I have a dask dataframe with a timestamp column, and I need to get day of the week and month from it.

Here is the ddf construction

```
dfs = [delayed(pd.read_csv)(path) for path in glob('../data/20*.zip')]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)

meta = ('starttime', pd.Timestamp)
df['start'] = df.starttime.map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, meta=meta)
```

now, if I use something like
`df.head(10).dt.year`, it works (returns a year). which means that datacol is converted.

However, when I try to get a new column, it raises an error:
`df['dow'] = df['start'].dt.dayofweek` (or any other ".dt" option, for that matter):

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `meta` isn't quite right (it raises an error for me on the latest dask and pandas). Here's a reproducible example that works

```
In [41]: import numpy as np

In [42]: import pandas as pd

In [43]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.date_range("2017", periods=12)})

In [45]: df['B'] = df.A.astype(str)

In [46]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)

In [47]: ddf['C'] = ddf.B.map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, meta=("B", "datetime64[ns]"))

In [48]: ddf.C.dt.dayofweek
Out[48]:
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=2
0     int64
6       ...
11      ...
Name: C, dtype: int64
Dask Name: dt-dayofweek, 12 tasks

In [49]: ddf.C.dt.dayofweek.compute()
Out[49]:
0     6
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     0
9     1
10    2
11    3
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Does that work for you? If not, could you edit your question to include a minimal example?

Comment: Note that you can also do `ddf['C'] = dd.to_datetime(ddf.B)` instead of using `map_partitions` at all.